# Android Monzo style switch button design

Tags: android, android-layout, ui-design

I am trying to create Monzo (Android) style switch in my android app. I managed to create it very close by custom drawable for Thumb and Track, but still not same.

Things still missing:

1. I gave top and bottom padding, but still not padding showing. There is no option of Margin in Thumb and Track drawable.
2. In Monzo app, both names are showing, but in my case name only showing based on switch on/off

I am attaching both screenshots - from Monzo App and from mine test app. I am also attaching my Thumb & Track drawables code.

Could someone please advise, how can I achieve same design. If Switch is not right component then which other component I can use.

Monzo:
[image: Monzo]

My App:
[image]

Thumb Drawable code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <size android:width="160dp"/>
            <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <size android:width="160dp"/>
            <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Track Drawable code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
            <size android:height="40dp"/>
            <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
            <padding android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp"
                android:left="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
            <size android:height="40dp"/>
            <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
            <padding android:top="10dp"
                    android:right="10dp"
                    android:bottom="10dp"
                    android:left="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_track">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llFeed"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_thumb"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvFeed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Feed"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llManage"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvManage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Manage"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Output for above :

[image]

Comment: I know it was not easy to explain via image. In actual on Monzo, these are buttons where it has slide animation. So above code will not work or I need to add complex animation to show them as button and slide from one side to another.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was able to solve this via setting Stroke for "Thumb" of the same color as "Track". Next issue was that it not displaying text on the track side...means when switch is off there was not text on other side.
The way I resolve that was by create 2 lables and constraint them to be on top of Switch, and i kept Switch On Off text as empty "".

Thumb Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <size android:width="160dp"/>
            <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
            <stroke android:color="@color/lightGray"
                android:width="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <size android:width="160dp"/>
            <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
            <stroke android:color="@color/lightGray"
                android:width="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```